# If Else Condition in Xml

Tags: xml, magento

I made a Custom module and I have made a system.xml , in which i am checking whether admin wants to include css or not
if admin choose one I am including one.css using below cod in my module layout.xml code

```
<action method="addCss" unlessconfig="mymodule/addcss/one"><stylesheet>mymodule/test/two.css</stylesheet></action>


<action method="addCss" ifconfig="mymodule/addcss/one"><stylesheet>mymodule/test/one.css</stylesheet></action>
```

now if admin choose no from backend it includes online two.css but when admin choose yes it includes both css one and two..
i just want to implement if else condition for including different different css .how can i achieve this without using third party extension.

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-layout-xml-conditions.html

Comment: i already checked that tutorial if works fine if admin choose no but when admin choose yes it includes both css. which is creating problem for me...

Comment: @KaranAdhikari: *If* you checked out that tutorial, then please make the code in your question reflect that. You've got a single line there in, but the tutorial requires two lines as you write that you have both CSS.

Comment: @hakre Please check the question again , i hope it would be clear to you now.

Comment: @KaranAdhikari: Checked. That's more clear. But are you sure, you've got the extension installed? Which version of the *Aoe_LayoutConditions* extension and which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: see i used unlessconfig without installing that extension .. but @kojiro cleared me that meagento doesn't support unlessconfig by default .. what i want now.. i just want to make if config is yes then css one should be included and if config is no then another css should be included. without using any module.

Answer (score 1):

The `unlessconfig` mentioned [in the article suggested in Meenakshi's comment](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-layout-xml-conditions.html) is added by the Aoe_LayoutConditions extension and is not in Magento core. See `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` for what features are available. That said, the class that has `addCss` (`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`) also has methods for removing items like css. So you should be able to do:

```
<action method="removeItem" ifconfig="mymodule/addcss/one">
    <stylesheet>mymodule/test/two.css</stylesheet>
    <type>skin_css</type>
</action>
<action method="addCss" ifconfig="mymodule/addcss/one">
    <stylesheet>mymodule/test/one.css</stylesheet>
</action>
```